# BlackBerry Eclipse Plugin Device not Found issue

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

I use BlackBerry Eclipse plugin for my development. From today it shows some problems. The problems are listed below.

First I try to run my project it dont response for some time and shows the message

```
Refreshing connection on send 1  Cancelling refresh - pending
```

then i run the clean.bat file for clearing simulator. After that showing the error

```
Device is not found in the BlackBerry SDK BlackBerry JRE 5.0.0
```

Now the simulators not found.

Any one faced similer situations? Now what i can do ?  can i install required simulators only? Or i install Blackberry JRE 5.0.0 Agin?

please help me.

Thank you

Comment: You should install simulators only because sometimes when we run clean.bat file then we get this type of problem. Install the simulator and run the application. Enough.

Comment: @alishaik786 THANKS , plase guide me how can i install simulator only?

Comment: Don't you have the simulator softwares.......?

Comment: yep.. Thanks... From morning everything goes wrong...Now everything fine.. thank you for your response... it works fine.. please post it an answer..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should install simulators only because sometimes when we run **clean.bat** file then we get this type of problem. Install the simulator and run the application. Enough.